after 1917 the bolsheviks started conquering again all the former nations of russian empire(including poland and finland) -was it legal?
since the russian king Nicolay II dethroned himself - was it legal for the new administration to conquer back freed nations?
what was the reason for the reds to come back and install their regime?
why did they think they had the right to conquer back the other nations?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)  "Legal" requires a frame of reference; when you define that term, you have your answer. They thought they had the right because they were engaged in permanent revolution.  Recommend  closure.

Sorry but the premise - that international law is enforceable and rigid like domestic law - is wrong. For the most part all governments do what they think they have to do to survive and prosper, and then come up with justifications afterwards. For that reason the question is unsalvageable and needs to be closed.

Yup. Wars are never "legal". That's why they bring the guns with them.

I'd point out that according to the pre-Bolshevik (tsarist) constitution of 1906, only Finland and Poland had separate "identities" (Finland much more, but still was inseparable), and their thrones were inseparable from that of Russia. So, for any nations to break away from the empire was utterly illegal, and reconquering them was equal to putting down those separatist rebellions. Whether Bolsheviks themselves took the power (from Kerensky) legally... that probably belongs to "might makes right" principle of the legality of coups d’État.

@RadovanGarabík - Perhaps, but if that governing entity ceased to exist, which it did in March of 1917, then any rules said government set up for itself are a dead letter.

Can I suggest why did they want to reclaim all of the Russian empire's territory as a better question?  The Bolsheviks didn't see themselves as the legal heirs of the empire - didn't pay its debts or adhere to its treaties - so there is a germ of a question here.

That the power in the Empire was transferred from the czar to Duma is, quite unrelated to the parts of the empire declaring independence. Moreover, Bolsheviks came to power only a few months later after the abdication. However on the process they did promise independence to many peoples in order to get their support and come to power (notably the Latvian rifleman - who formed the core of Bolshevik army for years.)

I don't see any edits that address the reason for closure, and I'm not entirely sure that this wouldn't be better served on the Law SE.  Cannot support re-open without addressing closure reason.

"Legal" is a meaningless fiction in regards to disputes between sovereign states. There is only that which the state can get away with - and that which it cannot get away with. The only "court" of relevance is that of public opinion; a court both notoriously fickle, and typically swayed much more by emotional than by rational, reasoned, or legal arguments.
Consider the 1982 Falklands War. Argentina gambled that it could take and hold the Malvinas archipelago because of the logistic difficulties for the U.K. in retaking them; and because it believed that they could sufficiently sway public opinion in the U.S. to make Reagan remain neutral during the conflict. It misjudged. Certainly where I resided the U.K. attempt to retake the Falklands was wildly popular, and Reagan opted to support the U.K. effort. But in the crunch, with modest U.S. aid and assistance U.K. managed to overcome the logistical problems and retake the archipelago.
So Falklands remain British not because of any legalities - but because the Argentinian attempt to "conquer" them was insufficient in the face of determined British opposition.

I think the first sentence is misleading. International law exists because states constraint their actions.  More importantly, reasoning from the first sentence leads to a misunderstanding of the Bolshevik's contempt for international law. I'm not saying that you're wrong, but IMO a different starting position leads to a clearer understanding.  (of course the one place I disagree is that I don't think a question with this much misunderstanding and confusion baked in should be answered)

@MCW: You are a diamond moderator - which means you had the means to immediately close the question if you think it's that bad. Yet, over the past 10+ years you and the other diamond moderators have consistently refused to do so. I regard every closed question with one or more answers a complete and utter failure of moderation. But if you and the other moderators refuse to close such questions, I will answer those few I believe are worthwhile object lessons.

Very good feedback.  My principle to defer to community prerogative. The community has the power to close a question, so I should not use my power (except where a question is offensive, illegal or otherwise actively dangerous).  If this post gets to four close votes, i'll happily cast the fifth.

@MCW: My key issue with the restraint is that it destroys the feedback loop motivating OP's to improve their questions. Perhaps you should never be the first close vote - but if there are two quick close votes (on this site, with relatively slow traffic) I believe you should be casting a definitive third vote.

From my station in the middle of the USA at the time, any plan Argentina had that they might get public opinion in the USA on their side also failed miserably.

@MCW On some sites (notably Latin, trying for Mythology), only 3 votes is necessary. 5 is great for a site like StackOverflow, but History isn't that busy that 3 should suffice. It's something that the mods have to ask for (or maybe the community can request in Meta).
